# Best data type for blog article with images in MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob

I am planning on starting a blog with articles that contain images (mostly these images will be used for explanatory purposes). The articles contents (text + images) will be stored in a MySQL database in one field in one table. My question is: is BLOB the best data type in MySQL to store these articles? I am open to table design recommendations as well.

Comment: Are you saying you'll store the images inside the Mysql database?

Comment: I was thinking of storing the article's content (text + images) in one field in a table in the database.

Comment: Better store a Link to the image in your database instead of an encoded Image. There has been long discussions about it whether you should do this or not. Also check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay . Since you are asking for a best practice I hope it was not to much offtopic

Comment: Images should be stored on the local filesystem, if you insist though, yeah use BLOB.

Comment: IMHO, you shouldn't do that, what I'll do in this case is store only the path of the image in the database in form of text :)

Comment: How exactly does one store images inside text?

Comment: @deceze Base64 encoded

Comment: @deceze for example as base64-encoded file contents, or straight binary after/between certain custom separator(s).

Comment: So you're going to send a giant base64 blob to the client? That prevents the client from caching the images separately, which is not great.

Comment: It is indeed not great, also for multiple perspectives. I guess SEO may a topic for you as well. So for this reason you should definately using real images :). Google likes images with alt tags